# Updating GCC on CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, gcc, centos

today I was trying to update my gcc and after a search on internet I've found this [article](http://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-6) but I got stuck. I did what it says but got an error just like my other attempts. On my other attempts I was thinking the links must be broken but in this case this is a new article and I thought something is wrong on my computer. In that article I was just using the update part since I've already have GCC 4.4.6 . And my problem is at the first step :D . I typed `sudo yum install svn texinfo-tex flex zip libgcc.i686 glibc-devel.i686` but here the terminal gives me the `Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again` I don't know what does that mean . Please don't make the question duplicate because I searched a lot but there is nothing about the error that I am getting. Thanks in advance.

Here is the `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` file as requested in the comments.

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-    6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: That means your `epel` repositories configuration in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` is incorrect (or you should just try again because it was a network error). What does that file contain? What version of `gcc` are you trying to install this way? Have you looked at the devtoolset-3 software collection for CentOS 6 it contains `gcc` 4.9.2. (I believe you can get it from http://softwarecollections.org currently but that it will be coming from CentOS officially at some point, possibly soon.)

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner . I took your advice and tried to download the devtoolset-3. I opened [here](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/). And typed the instructions but at the very first step it gives the same error. I also looked for the `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` file but it is a bit long for commenting here.

Comment: I don't think you need epel for devtoolset-3 so you can try adding `--disablerepo=epel` to the yum command and seeing if that helps (temporarily). If you don't need epel (you might not) you can disable it by default by editing the `epel.repo` file and changing `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` but that's not a solution just a workaround. Putting the file in a comment would have been a terrible idea anyway. Edit your post with the contents.

Comment: I' have made the change in the file and it  worked. Until step 4 :( . I think I'm going to give up :(

Comment: The mirrorlist entry for the `[epel]` repo is broken. You need to replace `epel-&` with `epel-6&`.

Comment: What failed at step four?

Answer (score 4):

---

Developer Toolset 2.0 http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo
```

You get **gcc-4.8.1** : `# yum install devtoolset-2-gcc-c++`

64bits http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6X/x86_64/RPMS/

32bits http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6X/i386/RPMS/

---

Comment: is this for scientifi linux? also is it working well with centos 6.x ?

Comment: No difference Redhat EL6.7 , CentOS 6.7 , ScientificLinux SL 6.7 ...... All the same. Same code base etc. ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/ .... And : Developer Toolset 2.0 is working OK in my CentOS 6.7 installs : `# yum install devtoolset-2-gcc-c++`

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure what you asking, but:

## EPEL

There is RPM that installs EPEL repo. Here is the link:

```
rpm -i http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Prior install, you need to remove the EPEL conf files you already applied.

Once installed, you need to do

```
yum update
```

and it will update whole system, including the gcc.

Note this update will **not** update CentOS to version 7 or something. It will only make all packages to last version - for example you will have last **supported** version of Apache webserver.

## GCC

Second part of the question is about gcc - even in EPEL, gcc is bit old. My own C++11 code, never compiles.

You need to install something called `redhat developer toolset 1.1`:
https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html/1.1_Release_Notes/ch-Features.html

To install it you need to create file as follows:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-1.1/devtools-1.1.repo 
yum --enablerepo=testing-1.1-devtools-6 install devtoolset-1.1-gcc devtoolset-1.1-gcc-c++
```

This will install it most likely into `/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/`.

This repo will not update anything outside `/opt/`.

to use the compiler, you need to export following variables:

```
export CC=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/gcc  
export CPP=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/c++
```

Sadly, even in this way, you can not get gcc 4.8, but gcc version is quite Ok. We were able to compile latest node.js with patching just one file, but we failed to compile latest TokuDB.

## CLANG

Did you ever tried `clang`? Because CentOS not depends of `clang`, it is quite new version, even *may* supports C++14.

Hope this helps.

Source for gcc repo:
https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos

Comment: I see someone already give you redhat dev tools repo. It instals in /opt, so you need to export bunch of environment variables such CC and CPP.

Comment: Thank you. This is my dorm's computer and it is an old one. This computer is also a server of a site so I can't update the OS. It can be doable btw but I don't know how to do it. Thanks for your help. I am giving up.

Comment: you do not need to update the OS. EPEL version is shown as 6.8 but it does not matter. 6.2 is same as 6.XX. yum update will just update the packages that needs to be updated. I said it, because often EPEL have newest version than regular repo. One comment for devtools repo - it does not update anything outside /opt and it is completly "harmless".

Comment: Hi, I did all of the things in [here](http://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos). And there was no problem. But `gcc --version` was still showing `4.4.7`. But then I saw [this](http://superuser.com/a/774893). Now it shows `gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5)`. But I can not still compile that code.

Comment: try with clang ?  you can always remove it? `yum install clang`